# 500 Internal Server Error Uber API request ride

Tags: android, request, uber-api

I am making a request to **POST /v1/requests** in response I receive **500 Internal Server Error**.

While when I request on sandbox environment I get response as

> {  "request_id": "a2368fba-9065-4a07-8924-2fcd29b8d2ff",  "status":
>   "processing",  "surge_multiplier": "1.0"  }

---

The request I am making is like

```
HashMap<String, String> obj = new HashMap<String, String>();
obj.put("product_id", product_id);
obj.put("start_latitude", String.valueOf(Constants.START_LATITUDE));
obj.put("start_longitude", String.valueOf(Constants.START_LONGITUDE));
obj.put("end_latitude", String.valueOf(Constants.END_LATITUDE));
obj.put("end_longitude", String.valueOf(Constants.END_LONGITUDE));

UberAPIClient.getUberV1APIClient().cabRequest(getAccessToken(), obj, new Request>() {
                @Override
                public void success(Request request, Response response) {


                        try {
                            JSONObject jb = new JSONObject(request.toString());
                            String request_id = jb.getString("request_id");
                            Intent i = new Intent(EndpointActivity.this, UberMapViewActivity.class);
                            i.putExtra("request_id", request_id);
                            startActivity(i);
                            finish();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println(e);
                        }



                    super.success(request, response);
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                    super.failure(error);
                });
```

---

```
 @POST("/requests")
    void cabRequest(@Header("Authorization") String authToken,
                    @Body HashMap<String, String> obj,
                    Callback<Request> callback);
```

However My app has full_access in request, all_trips and receipt. 
What can be the solution to this problem? I am not able to solve this issue.

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error, happens when there is any db error occur. Please try to get the error log and confirm that everything you did correct on your request

Comment: Eventually the data was not being processed from Uber server. Today it started working on its own for the same code.

Comment: 500 is for any error on the server side. not just DB